# Render angular 2 component in DOM node

Tags: angularjs, typescript, codemirror

I'm creating an Angular 2 application that uses CodeMirror as a source code editor. I'd like to add a line widget to it, which requires that I provide a DOM node to CodeMirror. I'd like to put some complex logic that depends on application data in this widget, so it will need to be an Angular component, however I can't figure out how to render an Angular element in a DOM Node (or whether it is even possible). Normally I would do it using a `ViewContainerRef`, but that doesn't work in this case.

Is there any way to achieve this using Angular 2?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ng2-codemirror (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-codemirror), that already takes care of that for you.

In anycase, if you need to get a DOM node from an Angular 2 component you can do something like this:

```
<div #element>
</div>
```

And then, on your typescript file you can:

```
import * as ng from "angular2/core";

export class MyComponent {
   @ng.ViewChild("element", {read: ng.ElementRef})
   element: ng.ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.element.nativeElement; // you dom node is here!
   }
}
```

Comment: That is just the CodeMirror element, I'm talking about a widget inside CodeMirror using the `addLineWidget` method on the CodeMirror.Editor instance